# Split Horizon DNS not working

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

I'm trying to get a split horizon dns server working on our network. bind9 starts up fine but when I point to the other servers resolf.conf to it I get these access denied messages. (For security reasons I have changed our website name to OURWEBSITE)

```
root@server:~# host zenoss
Host zenoss not found: 5(REFUSED)
root@server:~# host google.com
Host google.com.OURWEBSITE.com not found: 5(REFUSED)
```

and here is our named.conf

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
// include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

acl internal {
   192.168.168.0/25;
   localhost;
};

//
// Lan zone recursion is the default
//
view "internal-view" {
  match-clients { internal; };
  zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "/etc/bind/db.root";
  };
  zone "internal.OURWEBSITE.com " IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/lan.master.OURWEBSITE.com";
    allow-transfer { key TRANSFER; };
  };
};
//
// external zone w/o recursion
//
view "external-view" {
  match-clients { any; };
  recursion no;
  zone "OURWEBSITE.com " IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/internet.master.OURWEBSITE.com";
    allow-transfer { key TRANSFER; };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `allow-recursion { internal; };` to your internal view, as `{ localnets; localhost; };` is the default.

Oh, and is there other config in `named.conf.options`?  That should be included, too.